What to do with features causing data drift?
I dispose of labeled train data and unlabeled test data. I want to tune and validate a classifier on train data in such a way that it can have good performance on test.
By conducting some investigations, I noticed that the distributions of train and test are highly different. I trained a classification algorithm on the task consisting in recognize if a data point belongs to train or test. This yields AUC_score = 0.95.
y = np.zeros(len(total_df_all))
y[train_idx] = 1
XGBdata = xgb.DMatrix(data=total_df_all, label=y)
params = {"objective":"binary:logistic",
          "eval_metric":"logloss",
          'learning_rate': 0.05,
          'max_depth': 8, }
# perform cross validation with XGBoost
cross_val_results = cv(dtrain=XGBdata, params=params, 
                       nfold=5, metrics="auc", 
                       num_boost_round=200,early_stopping_rounds=20,
                       as_pandas=True)
print((cross_val_results["test-auc-mean"]).tail(1))

Afterwards I extracted the names of the features having the higher importance in this classifier.
def prune_divergent_features(data):
    total_df_all = data
    divergent_features = []
    score = 1
    while score >= 0.7:
        XGBdata = xgb.DMatrix(data=total_df_all, label=y)
        params = {"objective":"binary:logistic",
                "eval_metric":"logloss",
                'learning_rate': 0.05,
                'max_depth': 8, }
        # perform cross validation with XGBoost
        cross_val_results = cv(dtrain=XGBdata, params=params, 
                            nfold=5, metrics="auc", 
                            num_boost_round=200,early_stopping_rounds=20,
                            as_pandas=True)
        validated_auc = (cross_val_results["test-auc-mean"]).tail(1).values[0]
        classifier = XGBClassifier(eval_metric='logloss',use_label_encoder=False)
        classifier.fit(total_df_all, y)
        divergent = sorted(classifier.get_booster().get_fscore().items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item:item[1])[0][0]
        divergent_features.append(divergent)
        score = validated_auc
        total_df_all = total_df_all.drop([divergent], axis=1)
       
    return (score, divergent_features)

This code stops the extraction when the AUC score reaches 0.7.  This gives me about 149 drifting out of 280 features.

It is clear that dropping this amount of features will lead to a huge loss of information while training my model. So what can I do to mitigate this difference between train and test ?

I heard about a technique that consist in weighting the train set according to its KL divergence with the test set, but wouldn't it be considered as data leakage ?



Maybe a time-series model is required in this case.

@pentagonius Yes, this is what I thought but at that time I didn't have any info about when the data had been recorded.

Yann, Usually drift signifies change in data generating process, if there is some indication of that, one could tract it.
